# Сombine multiple SOLR fields into one

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have few dynamic Solr fields with similar pattern name (text_*) e.g. "text_1", "text_2", "text_3". I need to combine all such attributes into one multiValued attribute: ["text_1", "text_2", "text_3"]
I have tried to use the next approach with pattern:

```
 <dynamicField name="text_*" type="string" stored="true"/>
 <dynamicField name="allTexts"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true" stored="true"/>
 <copyField source="text_*" dest="allTexts"/>
```

But it is not working as SOLR face with the ERROR:

```
 Can't load schema /opt/.../managed-schema: Dynamic field name 'allTexts' should have either a leading or a trailing asterisk, and no others.
```

Maybe there is some other approach how it is possible to combine dynamic fields into one multiValued field by field name Pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define a regular field, not a dynamic field (which is that you've typed).

A dynamic field requires a wildcard to be present somewhere in the name (since that's what a dynamic field is - it supports wildcard matching of field names).

Swap it out with

```
<field name="allTexts"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true" stored="true" />
```